# T-SQL Count rows with specific values (Multiple in one query)

Tags: t-sql, count

I need some help with a T-SQL query. I want to count fields that have a special value(e.g. >1).

Assuming i have a table like:

```
IGrp | Item | Value1 | Value2
#############################
A    | I11  | 0.52   | 1.18
A    | I12  | 1.30   | 0.54
A    | I21  | 0.49   | 2.37
B    | I22  | 2.16   | 1.12
B    | I31  | 1.50   | 0.28
```

I want a result like:

```
IGrp | V1High | V2High 
######################
A    | 1      | 2
B    | 2      | 1
```

In my mind this should be going with this expression

```
SELECT IGrp, COUNT(Value1>1) AS V1High, COUNT(Value2>1) AS V2High
FROM Tbl GROUP BY IGrp
```

But that's not possible in T-SQL since the Count() does not take boolean values.
So is it really the only possible way to do multiple queries with `WHERE Value>1` and `COUNT(*)` and join them afterwards? Or is there a trick to accomplish the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
SELECT IGrp, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Value1 > 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS V1High, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Value2 > 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS V2High 
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY IGrp
```

Comment: Based on my experience SQL Server can work well with this command.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT IGrp, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Value1>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS V1High, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Value2>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS V2High 
FROM Tbl GROUP BY IGrp
```

Comment: This won't work. All non-null values are included in the count.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari no, check the edits, I corrected and the example is now correct.  If an answer is wrong on SO, it is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

make use of `case when` will do work for you

```
SELECT IGrp, 
 sum(case when isnull(Value1,0)>1 then 1 else 0 end) AS V1High, 
 sum(case when isnull(Value2,0)>1 then 1 else 0 end) AS V2High 
FROM Tbl GROUP BY IGrp
```

Comment: Thanks,
somehow i didn't thought of this.

Comment: This won't work. All non-null values are included in the count.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Your `CASE` statement returns either `1` or `0`, meaning that the `COUNT` is incremented in either case. Your `CASE` statement should return `NULL` when you don't want the count to be incremented.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IGrp, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Value1 = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Tot_Foo, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Value1 = 'Blah' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Tot_Blah 
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY IGrp
```

This can also be used to compare 2 different values for the same field, with minor changes as shown above.

Very helpful for verifying values that are supposed to exist in a 1:1 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a CASE .. WHEN .. statement inside the COUNT() functions to return 1 when the conditions hold, NULL otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
select
count(nullif(field > minvalue,false))
```